# Webpack Include Lodash Functions as Default

Tags: webpack

Is there a setup I can do in Webpack so I can have all the individual Lodash functions available as global-like variables? I am aware I can do this for Lodash itself under `_`, but can I export all the functions, so I can just call `forEach(…)` without doing `import { forEach } from ‘lodash’` in every module?

Comment: Why would you do that when `forEach` is a native function? The goal of Lodash is to help when the function is not available.